# Adding a marker in leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I followed a tutorial to make a very basic map with leaflet but the marker won't appear. How can I fix it so that it does?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
<title>Leaflet Web Map</title>
<style> #map {width: 1000px; height: 1000px;}</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
var map = L.map('map',{center: [0,0],zoom: 5});
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
var marker = L.marker([0,0]).addTo(mymap); // why is this not appearing?
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you don't have a set view like view-source:https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/example-overlays.html > var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

Comment: thanks but it still doesn't work, maybe i changed it wrong, I'll edit the question to reflect the change I made

Comment: here is a sample jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/abenrob/ZkC5M/

Answer (score 1):

You defined the map twice both as "map" and "mymap". The basemap was on map and the marker on mymap. The code below will work, I also moved your marker coords North of the equator so it would show on your map.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
<title>Leaflet Web Map</title>
<style> #map {width: 1000px; height: 1000px;}</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>

var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 11);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var marker = L.marker([51.6,0]).addTo(map); 

</script>
</body>
</html>
```